# echo issue in android pjsua2 (pjsip) android

Tags: android, pjsip

I have integrated pjsip for Android and every thing is fine. But I am having only one problem that is echo.

Here is mycode in `MyApp.java`

```
/* Set media config. */
MediaConfig media_cfg =epConfig.getMedConfig();
media_cfg.setSndAutoCloseTime(0);
media_cfg.setEcOptions(2);
media_cfg.setEcTailLen(100);
```

Your help help will be appreciated.

Comment: Put question on pjsip group thread .Hope it will help.Also see this http://www.pjsip.org/pjmedia/docs/html/group__PJMEDIA__Echo__Cancel.htm

Comment: did you find a solution to this, we have the same problem when we use the speakers

Comment: we moved to the latest pjsip version (from SVN) and integrated the WebRTC echo cancellation as described here: https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/ticket/1888#no1 it works quite well for now

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
static class pjmedia_echo_flag {
            static long PJMEDIA_ECHO_WEBRTC = 3,
                    PJMEDIA_ECHO_USE_NOISE_SUPPRESSOR = 128,
                    PJMEDIA_ECHO_AGGRESSIVENESS_AGGRESSIVE = 0x300;
        }

    epConfig.getMedConfig().setEcOptions(pjmedia_echo_flag.PJMEDIA_ECHO_WEBRTC|
                pjmedia_echo_flag.PJMEDIA_ECHO_USE_NOISE_SUPPRESSOR|
                pjmedia_echo_flag.PJMEDIA_ECHO_AGGRESSIVENESS_AGGRESSIVE);
```

Comment: Actually what worked for me was to inform Android API about ongoing call.

Comment: can you plz provide the snippet for us.

Comment: Yes sure, test this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45691502/7430250

Comment: I don`t think this is working code. as per my knowledge, we should use only PJMEDIA_ECHO_WEBRTC.